# ConfigureAwait(false) - Does the continuation always run on different thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

This question is asked in the context of [ASP.NET WebApi 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) (not ASP.NET Core). I have tried to do my own research on this topic, however I could not find the explicit answer to this.

The official [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait?view=netframework-4.7.2#) for the `ConfigureAwait(...)` method parameter states following:

> `true` to attempt to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured; otherwise, `false`.

[Stephen Toub](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/782#issuecomment-403616976) further explains the `attempt` keyword as follows:

> That means there may not be anything to marshal back to... there may not be a context to capture, e.g. `SynchronizationContext.Current` may return `null`.

If I understand it correctly, then this is not the case for the ASP.NET WebApi 2, because there is `AspNetSynchronizationContext` present, right?

Now lets take a look at following controller action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<String> GetValues()
{
    // First half.

    var values = await HeavyIo().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Second half.

    return values;
}
```

By passing `continueOnCapturedContext: false` is it guaranteed that that the continuation labeled as `// Second half.` gets **always** executed on different thread? Or is there chance that **if** the thread on which the synchronization context got captured will be free when async operation completes, **then** the continuation will run on that same thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When asked in the negative form like that the answer is, i think, pretty clear - there is no guarantee that the second half will be executed on a different thread to the first half. As you speculate, the original thread might well be the lucky next-to-be-picked available thread, when the continuation is up for executing.

Also important to note is that it's the *context*, not necessarily the *thread*, that is restored. In the case of a Windows message loop (e.g. WinForms UI thread), it is the UI thread running the message loop that picks up and executes the continuation, hence with `ConfigureAwait(true)`, the same thread is guaranteed. With other SynchronizationContexts, though, there might be no particular reason to require or even prefer the original thread, as long as whatever is considered by them to be "context" is restored; e.g. `HttpContext.Current` [, identity, culture] in ASP.NET.

There is also an at-least theoretical chance that `HeavyIo()` completes synchronously, in which case there is no context-switching anyway, and the second half will simply continue on the same thread as the first. I can only assume from your choice of naming ("heavy") that you're implying this won't be an option.

Answer (score 0):

In your example no it is not guaranteed that it will run on a different thread as it depends what HeavyIO does.

If HeavyIO did this then it would guarantee the that "second half" was always a different thread.

```
private async Task<string> HeavyIo1()
{
    string test = "";
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Call some syncronous library thats very slow

    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return test;
}
```

If HeavyIO for example did the following if the date was > 2011 it would return on the same thread as "first half". If the date was before 2011 it would return on a different thread.

```
private async Task<string> HeavyIo2()
{

    if (DateTime.Now > new DateTime(2011, 1, 1)) return null;

    string test = "";
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Call some syncronous library thats very slow
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return test;
}
```